# \tableofcontents does not appear

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

A table of contents does not appear in my beamer document. How do I make it appear? I have the following code (for linebreak I wanted to add 2 spaces at end of `\part[square]{round}` but that didn't work so the code block is a tad dense, any comments on this are welcome too):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}  
\frame{\titlepage}
\frame{\tableofcontents}
\part[square]{round}  
\begin{frame}  \frametitle{One} Content \end{frame}   
\section{First Section}  
\begin{frame}  \frametitle{Two} Content \end{frame} 
\subsection{First Sub-Section}   
\begin{frame}  \frametitle{Three} Content \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always post a _complete_ document. Here you just need to add the `\documentclass` so I added it for you.

Comment: Thanks @PeterGrill. Apologies. I will add it myself next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's `\part[square]{round}`supposed to do? Beamer doesn't support parts, AFAIK.

**ETA**: Please see comments below.

This works for me as expected:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \frame{\titlepage}

    \begin{frame}[label=toc]
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}  
        \frametitle{One} Content 
    \end{frame}   

    \section{First Section}  

    \begin{frame} 
        \frametitle{Two} Content 
    \end{frame} 

    \section{Second Section}  
    \subsection{First Sub-Section}   

    \begin{frame}  
        \frametitle{Three} Content 
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Of course you'll have to compile your file twice, as is always the case with TOCs.

Comment: Yes thank you I have used your solution. Also for returning users who may find that they have the same problem... I am using Latexian with livepreview and it seems the toc does not appear in the livepreview window. I had to set "Number of Typesetter Runs at End > 2" in the program>edit>preferences and use the "Preview" button to view the PDF (rather than expect to see it in the livepreview pane).

Comment: But of course `beamer` supports parts; please see Section **10.3
Adding Parts** of the beamermanual.

Comment: I stand corrected.